# Can I change the default timestamp interpretation in pandas read_json

Tags: python, json, pandas, timestamp

I have a JSON data file with an unfortunately named "timestamp" field. The timestamp is formatted as **`"%y%m%d%H%M%S"`** but pandas.json_read() interprets this as a UNIX epoch timestamp so the field is interpreted as sometime in 1975.

Is there a way to override the read_json behavior to provide a format specifier - similar to what pandas.to_json(...,date_format="...")) does?

```
import StringIO
import pandas as pd
my_json_data='''[
  {
    "itemId": "alpha:136:1",
    "testTime": 12.449,
    "workTime": 152.5,
    "project": "alpha",
    "user": "user100021-su7d",
    "timestamp": "170520161430",
    "accuracy": 1
  },
  {
    "itemId": "alpha:136:10",
    "testTime": 4.114,
    "workTime": 152.5,
    "project": "alpha",
    "user": "user100021-su7d",
    "timestamp": "170520161430",
    "accuracy": 0.8890000000000001
  },
  {
    "itemId": "alpha:136:100",
    "testTime": 5.114,
    "workTime": 43.4,
    "project": "alpha",
    "user": "user100021-su7d",
    "timestamp": "170522150338",
    "accuracy": 0.875
  }
]
'''

my_df = pd.read_json(StringIO.StringIO(my_json_data))
my_df["timestamp"]
```

output is:

```
0   1975-05-28 14:42:41.430
1   1975-05-28 14:42:41.430
2   1975-05-28 15:15:50.338
Name: timestamp, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, I couldn't find a similar option in the Pandas documentation, but this workaround should do:

```
my_df = pd.read_json(StringIO.StringIO(my_json_data),convert_dates = False)
my_df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(my_df['timestamp'],format='%y%m%d%H%M%S')
print my_df["timestamp"]
```

I am simply asking pandas to not process the strings to date time while reading the JSON, and then am manually doing it later by providing the format. This should display the dates correctly.

Comment: thanks - this does accomplish what i wanted. it seems like something that should be allowed through the conversion options though.